# TypeError: $(...).linkButton is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, typeerror

So I have an HTML form that has multiple sections.  Each sections includes similar parts (submit section, instructions, etc.). Below is code directly from Firebug debugger.  It has my page specific script code then below it some inputs, then the included script code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var x = 0;

function isNumberKey(evt) {
     var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
     if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
       return false; 

     return true;
  }

$(document).ready(function () {

// Lots of JQuery here
});   
</script>

<br /><br /><div class="submit">
<input type="submit" id="save" name="save" class="save" value="SAVE" />
<input type="reset" id="reset" name="reset" value="RESET" class="save" />
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="SAVE & NEXT" />
<input type="button" id="previous" name="previous" value="PREVIOUS" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#previous").linkButton({
    "newLocation" : "Verification.jsp"      });   // ERROR on this line!
});
</script>
</div>

</form>
```

I get a TypeError: $(...).linkButton on the " "newLocation" : "Verification.jsp"      });" line above.  The confusing thing is that I have multiple other sections (15+) that use this include script without an error.  So I have a feeling it has to do with me adding the page specific jQuery.  Any help would be appreciated because I am not sure where to even start.

Comment: Just means you don't have loaded your linkButton jquery plugin yet.

Comment: Like I said, I have over 15 other pages using that plugin, so I dont think that is the problem.

Comment: That must be the problem. Add a breakpoint before the error and try to log `$.fn.linkButton` which will be a function if your plugin is actually loaded.